# How to use Future and Callable in my own thread pool implementation

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, future, callable

I am trying to implement my own thread pool in Java (for didactic purposes).

In my thread pool class, I have this method:

```
public Future submit (Task task) { //(Task implements Callable<String>)
    FutureTask<String> futureTask = new FutureTask<String>(task);
    taskQueue.put(task); //It is a BlockingQueue
    return futureTask;
}
```

I am wrapping my Task into a FutureTask, put it in a synchronized queue and immediately return the FutureTask.

When I am trying to add tasks to the pool, I do:

```
   Future<String> futureTask = threadPool.submit(new Task(/*arguments*/));
   //In theory, I could do something else here
   String taskRes = futureTask.get();
```

I use the above code with some threads, but futureTask.get() never returns.

My threads do something like this:

```
public void run() {
  Task task = taskQueue.take();
  task.call();
}
```

**Is there something logically wrong on how I used Future and Callable?**

I mean a Task is wrapped into a FutureTask in one thread, but it is called in another one. For some reasons futureTask.get() can not get the return value of task.call().

Comment: Stupid question, do you call FutureTusk.run() anywhere?

Comment: No, run() is just the code of my threads. They just take a task and execute it with call(). My assumption is that, since I wrapped the task into a FutureTask, futureTask.get() will know when task.call() ends. Maybe I got something wrong here.

Comment: Your code can’t look like you have posted. You are putting instances of `FutureTask` into the queue, so it’s impossible that you are retrieving instances of you custom `Task` class at the other end. If the worker threads correctly `take` the (`Runnable`)  `FutureTask`s from the queue, there is no ambiguity any more, they have to invoke `run()` as there is no `call()`. Besides that, if your threads have the logic as shown, i.e. execute a single task only, you must start a new thread each time you submit a new task as otherwise, there will be no running worker threads sooner or later.